# Conda's version information on package doesn't correspond to __version__

Tags: python, conda, dill

I'm using anaconda

```
(myenv3) foo@foo:~$ which conda
/home/foo/anaconda3/bin/conda
```

where in "myenv3" I have `dill=2.8.2` installed:

```
(myenv3) foo@foo:~$ conda list -n myenv3 dill
# packages in environment at /home/foo/anaconda3/envs/myenv3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
dill                      0.2.8.2                  py36_0    conda-forge
```

If I run `python`, I'll get exactly that environment:

```
(myenv3) foo@foo:~$ which python
/home/foo/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/bin/python
```

But if I do, `dill` appears to have an older version:

```
(myenv3) foo@foo:~$ python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> dill.__version__
'0.2.7.1'
```

Apparently, the file comes from elsewhere:

```
>>> dill.__file__
'/home/foo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/__init__.py'
```

It appears that in my include path, `.local` dominates the conda-specific folder:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/foo/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python36.zip', '/home/foo/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6', '/home/foo/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/foo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/home/foo/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

Why -- and how can I fix that?

**Context**: I'm sharing `dill`-ed files between different computers. I started getting a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dill._dill'` error when reading the files on my local computer. I suspect this is because these files are dilled with the newer version, and my local computer is trying to read them with the older one. To test that, I'd like to upgrade `dill` on my local computer (or make the environment run the version it actually claims it is).

Comment: How about `dill.__file__`?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @Sraw's comment for the pointer. To check which file is actually being read, do

```
>>> dill.__file__
'/home/foo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/__init__.py'
```

The reason for that can be found in the include path:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/foo/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python36.zip', '/home/foo/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6', '/home/foo/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/foo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/home/foo/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

This particular path corresponds to `pip`. It's supposed to not install packages that are already installed with `conda`, but apparently it made a mistake here. Also it is unclear to me why the `pip` folder dominates the `conda` folder in the ordering, but it is what it is.

```
pip list
```

verified that it has the older version installed, and

```
pip uninstall dill
```

removed that old version.

Comment: It's not that the `pip` folder dominates the `conda` folder, but that packages in the `~/.local/...` always get added to the `sys.path` first. This is true for "regular" Python as well, packages installed with e.g., `sudo apt ...` will come after packages installed with `pip --user` in the `sys.path`.